# Installing Ubuntu Desktop 64Bit to Server?

Tags: 17.10

Images I see when I try to install Ubuntu Desktop,

http://img.awfordjr.net/uploads/big/e8710bfa7d4c1cb3501a576c705a5a99.jpg

http://img.awfordjr.net/uploads/big/cea5ef88656df8bd225f11e3d554aab8.jpg

http://img.awfordjr.net/uploads/big/f1109ba5286f289e958172897f1f04fd.jpg

And in that order... Except the middle one shows up with a crappy green glow around it which is not normal as it doesn't do that on my laptop. I would assume its the crap on-board video doing that, but I got this server with Linux installed on it but it had a password I did not know so I reformatted. Its been hell ever since other then when I install Windows which works fine, I just prefer Linux.

Every time I try to install any version of Ubuntu Desktop 64Bit it comes up to the screen where Ubuntu Logo Text should show me options about what I want to do next such as install Ubuntu, but instead the text "UBUNTU" is shown on the lower right side of my screen 50% off the screen. My mouse is moveable but I am not able to do anything.

So if I click <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>ALT</kbd>+<kbd>F4</kbd>, is there a text option to which I can use to install Ubuntu without the need to worry with the glitched GUI at the install screen?

If not what are my other options of getting it installed on my server?

Thanks for your time, help, and support!

Comment: Ubuntu Mate installed flawlessly, so why wont Ubuntu? I am really confused...

Comment: Which version of ubuntu are you trying?